# Increment Number in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have numbers like `32,33,33.1,33.2,34,34.1,35,35.1,35.2,35.3,35.4,36` and so on. Now is it possible that if I will change the number 32 to 52, then all respective numbers will also change like `52,53,53.1,53.2,54,54.1,55,55.1,55.2,55.3,55.4,56` may be using regexp pattern or anything.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Regular Expressions cannot perform mathematical functions on the values which they find. However, for finding numbers which begin with '3' and making them start with '5', this Regex will suffice:

Find:

```
3([0-9]*\.*[0-9]*)
```

Replace:

```
5\1
```

If you want to carry on into the 40s, 50s, etc, then the first number in each of these expressions will need to be modified.

Comment: It is difficult to do this using Regexp in notepad++. So I have done that in java. Sometimes coding is better..

Comment: @user1788115, if you already knew how to do this, why didn't you just do this?